# Overlay a local .TIFF file in folium leaflet?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, leaflet, raster, folium

I've been using folium to overlay earth engine images in a leaflet in Python.

I'm trying to get a local .TIFF raster to also display, but I only get an empty box in the bounds where the raster should be.

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.plot import show

img = "./PermafrostNSIDC_2002-02-01_rgb_3600x1800.TIFF"

show(rio.open(img))
```

This displays my image, showing that the filepath is correct

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[67.214,153.327],zoom_start=5)

image = folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
        name="Permafrost",
        image = img, 
        bounds=[[25, -180], [80, 180]],
        interactive=True,
        zindex=1,
    )

image.add_to(m)
```

This just adds an empty bounds box to the map.

Is there any way to get local .TIFF raster files to display on folium map or in this kind of leaflet?

Comment: I think you can use it by converting it to PNG format.[Raster Layers](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#module-folium.raster_layers)

Comment: You can refer to my question which I posted in his stack exchange wherein I am able to successfully plot or display the tif file onto the folium map...."https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393938/plotting-landsat-image-on-folium-maps"....